# Panel não fica invisivel se o evento paint de chart é ativado

Tags: c#, panel, mschart

Boa noite,

Pessoal gostaria de uma ajuda, to com uma duvida, bom estou desenvolvendo um aplicação, na qual o usuario escolhe 5 datas quaisquer de dias uteis do mês,e gera um gráfico diferenciado com a cotação de cada dia, certo, esse grafico diferenciado (Triangulos e linhas) é feito a partir do Evento Paint, que possui um if que só espera um valor true para uma bool para fazer as formas, quando o usuario escolhe as datas e clica no botão "Gerar" era para o panel de opções de data ficar visible=false, porem ao ser setado o valor da variavel bool para o evento paint como true, e o paint começar a rodar, essa panel não some ficando na tela, ja tentei colocar a linha de visible dentro do if do paint não adiantou também. Se alguém souber o porque disso acontecer, e me mostrar como arrumar agradeço

Print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV2T2.jpg

```
private void btGerarGraficos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listaPETR3 = acessar.carregarPregoes(cbData1.Text, cbData2.Text, cbData3.Text, cbData4.Text, cbData5.Text, "PETR3");
            listaPETR4 = acessar.carregarPregoes(cbData1.Text, cbData2.Text, cbData3.Text, cbData4.Text, cbData5.Text, "PETR4");

            GerarGraficosCandles();

            CriarPontosTriangulos();

            pnlConfigurarDatas.Visible = false;

            if (checkPETR3.Checked)
            {
                drawPETR3Banco = true;
            }

            if (checkPETR4.Checked)
            {
                drawPETR4Banco = true;
            }
        }

    private void chartPETR4_Paint_Banco(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (drawPETR4Banco)
        {
            double posiX, open, close, max, min;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                i++;
                posiX = chartPETR4.ChartAreas["areaTriangulo4"].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(i);
                i--;
                open = chartPETR4.ChartAreas["areaTriangulo4"].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(listaPETR4[i].Abertura);
                close = chartPETR4.ChartAreas["areaTriangulo4"].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(listaPETR4[i].Fechamento);
                max = chartPETR4.ChartAreas["areaTriangulo4"].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(listaPETR4[i].Maximo);
                min = chartPETR4.ChartAreas["areaTriangulo4"].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(listaPETR4[i].Minimo);

                if (listaPETR4[i].Abertura < listaPETR4[i].Fechamento)
                {
                    Point[] posicoes = {
                                           new Point(Convert.ToInt32(posiX) - 20, Convert.ToInt32(open)),
                                           new Point(Convert.ToInt32(posiX) + 20, Convert.ToInt32(open)),
                                           new Point(Convert.ToInt32(posiX) + 20, Convert.ToInt32(close))
                                       };
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, Convert.ToInt32(posiX), Convert.ToInt32(min), Convert.ToInt32(posiX), Convert.ToInt32(max));
                    e.Graphics.FillPolygon(bVerde, posicoes);
                }

                else if (listaPETR4[i].Abertura > listaPETR4[i].Fechamento)
                {
                    Point[] posicoes = {
                                           new Point(Convert.ToInt32(posiX) + 20, Convert.ToInt32(close)),
                                           new Point(Convert.ToInt32(posiX) - 20, Convert.ToInt32(open)),
                                           new Point(Convert.ToInt32(posiX) - 20, Convert.ToInt32(close))
                                       };
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, Convert.ToInt32(posiX), Convert.ToInt32(min), Convert.ToInt32(posiX), Convert.ToInt32(max));
                    e.Graphics.FillPolygon(bVermelho, posicoes);
                }
            }
            chartPETR4.Invalidate(true);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Jovem, poste o código.

Comment: é meio extenso vou colocar o código do evento click do botão e o evento paint do chart na real são dois charts mas se arrumar em um é só mudar no outro que é parecido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de alterar a variável para true ou false, você deve pintar novamente o chart.

O código ficaria assim:

`pnlConfigurarDatas.Visible = false;`

if (checkPETR3.Checked)
{
  drawPETR3Banco = true;
}

if (checkPETR4.Checked)
{
  drawPETR4Banco = true;
}
chartPETR4.Refresh();
chartPETR3.Refresh();

Eu também tiraria esses if's.
Código final:

pnlConfigurarDatas.Visible = false;

drawPETR3Banco = checkPETR3.Checked;
drawPETR4Banco = checkPETR4.Checked;

chartPETR4.Refresh();
chartPETR3.Refresh();

Comment: Obrigado amigo :), po é mesmo burrice a minha usar os if's SAUushSUHuASUSH mas obrigado ai